# html2canvas call causes jQuery click to need two clicks for function to work

Tags: jquery, click, html2canvas

I've read all the questions with the same problem but no success.
I've tried `trigger()`, `unbind('click')`, `on('click', function())`, `live('click')`, etc

My problem is that I have to click twice on the save button to validate and submit the data to the database and return a message of `'success'` or `'fail`' to display error message.

JQUERY

```
$('.save').click(function (event) {
    // GET CATEGORIA
    var category_change = 0;
    if (!$('#new_category').val()) {
        category = $('#categoria_id').val();
    } else {
        category = $('#new_category').val();
        category_change = 1;
    }

    // GET TITLE
    var title = $('input#title').val();

    // GET IMAGE
    var target = $('#parent');
    html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            image = canvas.toDataURL();
        }
    });

    // GET FORMATED CODE
    var array = ["n", "e", "s", "w"];
    var format = $('#parent').html();
    var strrep = '<div class="close">X</div>';
    var strrep2 = '<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>';

    var aux2 = 0;
    while (aux2 < 5) {
        $.each(array, function () {
            format = format.replace('<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-' + this + '" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>', '');
        });
        format = format.replace(strrep, '');
        format = format.replace(strrep2, '');
        aux2++;
    }
    var code = '<div id="parent">' + format + '</div>';


    if (title != '' && $('.child').length != 0) {
        $('.db_result').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');
        $.post("db_prox.php", {
            category: category,
            title: title,
            image: image,
            code: code,
            category_change: category_change
        }, function (post_result) {
            alert('2');
            if (post_result == 'success') {
                $('.db_result').text('O template foi guardado com sucesso!');
                $('.continue').prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $('.db_result').text('Ocorreu um erro na gravação do template!');
            }
        });
    }

    // INSERIR NA BASE DE DADOS CLOSE
});
```

PHP db_prox.php

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/functions.php';

$categoria = $_POST['category'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$nova_categoria = $_POST['category_change'];

if($nova_categoria == 1){

    $result = get_cat_last_created();
    $cat_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $aux_id = $cat_id['categoria_id'] + 1;
    $query = "INSERT INTO categorias (categoria_id, name) VALUES ('$aux_id', '$categoria')";
    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO templates (categoria_id, title, image, code) VALUES ('$aux_id', '$title', '$image', '$code')";

        if(mysqli_query($connection, $query2)) {
            echo "success";
        }
        else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO templates (categoria_id, title, image, code) VALUES ('$categoria', '$title', '$image', '$code')";
    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        echo "fail";
    }
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you try reducing the code to a bare minimum example and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, if I do that it will let me click once to execute. But I need all the GET's to happen after the save button is clicked.

Comment: you should you worry about security of your code, sql Injection is almost predictible

Comment: how can I avoid sql injection in the above code?

Comment: @circle73 This takes time, but it will end up being faster than waiting for someone else to figure it out: reduce your code to what works, then add back the rest one step at a time.

Comment: What does `html2canvas` do? If you comment that call out does it work?

Comment: "But I need all the GET's to happen" - what GET's? I see no GET's here.

Comment: the problem is exactly the plugin html2canvas. If I comment it out it will run with single click. How can I force the html2canvas function to run and give me the base64 code and store in the var image without giving me the double click problem?

Comment: Negative conditionals `if (!$('#new_category').val()) {
        category = $('#categoria_id').val();
    } else {
        category = $('#new_category').val();
        category_change = 1;
    }` are better written as positive `if ($('#new_category').val()) {
        category = $('#new_category').val();
        category_change = 1;
    } else { category = $('#categoria_id').val();}`

Comment: I have edited your question to clarify that it is related to the `html2canvas` call. Please take steps to isolate that code causes the failure - at least per your comment.

Comment: If you change `html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        image = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});` to prepend `var image=''; html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        image = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});` does that change things?  OR do you need to encode the `image` value before sending it?

Comment: If I do that it jumps the html2canvas part and stores the image variable with null

Comment: Is there a way to force the html2canvas to attribute a value to var image using trigger? so that the $('.save').click execution only continues when the function html2canvas has been successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onrendered` function is asynchronous in

```
 html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        image = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});
```

meaning that whatever code that is synchronously run right after that doesn't have the `image` variable assigned yet.

Moving your ajax post inside the `onrendered` function will make it send the request once the image has been created, i.e:

```
 html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        image = canvas.toDataURL();
        $.post("db_prox.php", {
          category: category,
          title: title,
          image: image,
          code: code,
          category_change: category_change
        }, function (post_result) {
          alert('2');
          if (post_result == 'success') {
            $('.db_result').text('O template foi guardado com sucesso!');
            $('.continue').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            $('.db_result').text('Ocorreu um erro na gravação do template!');
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Niklas! Great great plugin you have here. I was about to try to contact you. This solution worked great for the issue above. But now I have another problem. I don't know if there is a limit of size this plugin can output in image jpeg but now when I'm running it, all the images come rendered just until half of the div #parent. Is there a way to extend the size limit so the image is outputed in it's totality?

Comment: @circle73 By default, `toDataURL` returns a png image. Does the div #parent have overflow scroll set?

Comment: I'm using this method to return the image as a jpeg `image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");` this are the css for `#parent` : `#parent{ width: 800px; height: 600px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: solid 2px gray; padding: 0; overflow: scroll; }`